# `ng-select` can not binding property on start

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

I have something like this:

```js
<ng-select class="sekcja_select"
  [items]="arrayPermissionsObject"
  [virtualScroll]="true"
  (change)="function($event)"
  placeholder="Name of object"
  bindLabel="name"
  bindValue="id"
  formControlName="permissions"
></ng-select>
```

`arrayPermissionsObject = []{id: string, name: string}`

If I bind this from list, it's fine, but if I try load to edit, I've blank field in `<ng-select>`.

`ngForm = permissions: [zad ? zad.permissions : new FormControl(-1)]`

I have no ideas about this.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you crate stackblitz with reproducible issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I missed the method

[compareWith]="compareFunction"

```
compareFunction(item: List, selected: string) {
return item.id === selected.toString();
```

}